# Problemas con FontAwesome Icon en Next JS

Tags: typescript, nextjs

Estoy tratando de depolyar un repo en Git. Fue creado Con TS y NextJS. Me tira el siguiente error. Creo que va por el lado de las dependencias. Instale, desistanle fontawesome y nada. Si alguno sabe algo, se lo agradezco. Muchas gracias.

Type error: Type 'IconDefinition' is not assignable to type 'IconProp'.

```
<div className='aside-menu__header'>
            <HeaderCart className={'cart-header cart-header_horizontal'} />
            <button className='btn' onClick={closeIfOpened} >
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimes} />
            </button>
```